# Формирование SQL запроса в python

Tags: python, sql

Выполняю в цикле такой код:

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO items (res_id, log_id, link, title, content, n_date, nd_date, s_date, not_date)'''
                        values = ''' VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ''' % (
                                res_id,
                                log_id,
                                resource_link,
                                item_title,
                                item_content,
                                n_date,
                                nd_date,
                                s_date,
                                not_date)
                        result = sql + values
```

В итоге  в данный момент у меня в `result` хранятся такие данные:

```
INSERT INTO items (res_id, log_id, link, title, content, n_date, nd_date, s_date, not_date) VALUES ('35', '1', 'http://bryansk-news.net/society/2019/10/07/37428.html', 'бла-бла'
', 'Added by Raha', '1570402602', '1570429215.989103', '2019-10-07') 
INSERT INTO items (res_id, log_id, link, title, content, n_date, nd_date, s_date, not_date) VALUES ('35', '1', 'http://bryansk-news.net/society/2019/10/07/37429.html', 'бла-бла'
', 'Added by Raha', '1570402845', '1570429217.0539544', '2019-10-07')
```

А мне надо чтобы данные были в такие:

```
INSERT INTO items (res_id, log_id, link, title, content, n_date, nd_date, s_date, not_date) VALUES ('35', '1', 'http://bryansk-news.net/society/2019/10/07/37428.html', 'бла-бла'
', 'Added by Raha', '1570402602', '1570429215.989103', '2019-10-07') 
VALUES ('35', '1', 'http://bryansk-news.net/society/2019/10/07/37429.html', 'бла-бла'
', 'Added by Raha', '1570402845', '1570429217.0539544', '2019-10-07')
```

Как это можно сделать?
**UPD:** Отличие первого варианта от второго в том что,в первом варианте `INSERT INTO` присутствует 2 раза.А во втором `INSERT INTO` присутствует всего 1 раз и также во втором варианте `VALUES` присутствует 1 раз

Comment: Может вы расскажете чем одни данные отличаются от других и откуда берется разница. На первый взгляд одно и то же.

Comment: Почему вы решили отказаться от нормального и гибкого варианта с защитой от SQL injections в пользу этого варианта?

Comment: @Эникейщик, в первом варианте там два раза написано `INSERT INTO items` а втором один раз написан `INSERT INTO items` но два раза написано `VALUES`

Comment: @MaxU,просто мне интересно,я хочу произвести некий "бенчмарк" )

Comment: Вынесите переменную sql из цикла и переменную result создавайте после цикла

Comment: @MaxU, а по другому никак? "и переменную result создавайте после цикла"

Comment: Просто в цикле делаете values += ‘’’... Не понимаю в чем проблема

Comment: @MaxU,проблема? В том что я не пойму понять как мне сделать чтобы во втором `INSERT INTO` присутствовал всего один раз и также во втором варианте VALUES присутствовал 2 раза

Comment: *во втором INSERT INTO присутствует всего один раз и также во втором варианте VALUES присутствует 2 раза* С точки зрения сервера БД второй запрос синтаксически неверен. `VALUES` в нём должен присутствовать только 1 раз, а дальше должны идти блоки данных через запятую, каждый блок в скобках. Т.е. `INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES (data1), (data2)`.

Comment: @Akina, Почему же ? Я могу сделать так `INSERT INTO MyTable
  ( Column1, Column2, Column3 )`
`VALUES
  ('John', 123, 'Lloyds Office'), 
  ('Jane', 124, 'Lloyds Office'), 
  ('Billy', 125, 'London Office'),
  ('Miranda', 126, 'Bristol Office')`

Comment: Так что: отдельно формируете переменную начала запроса, включая VALUES. Отдельно формируете блоки данных в скобках, в массиве. Затем джойните массив через запятую и лепите на хвост к началу запроса.

Comment: *Я могу сделать так* Так - можете. Это - правильно, слово `VALUES` присутствует только один раз.

Comment: Можно слово VALUES перенести в переменную sql ...

Comment: @Akina,Прошу прошения.Я не правильно выразился в начале.Да я хочу чтобы было так **слово VALUES присутствует только один раз**

Comment: Ну я выше рассказал, как этого добиться. Или можете обойтись без массива, безусловно лепя запятую в начале либо в конце, а потом при конкатенации обрезав лишнюю.

Comment: *во втором INSERT INTO присутствует всего 1 раз и также во втором варианте **VALUES присутствует 1 раз*** Пересчитайте ещё раз...\

Comment: @Akina,**безусловно лепя запятую в начале либо в конце, а потом при конкатенации обрезав лишнюю** оформите свой комментарий как ответ чтобы я его отметил )

Comment: Не могу - я не знаю питоновского синтаксиса. И рыться в документации и смотреть, как оно должно выглядеть синтаксически правильно, у меня нет никакого желания. Напишите сами правильный ответ - это не возбраняется. И постарайтесь сделать его аргументированным и обозримым (укоротите вставляемые строки, чтобы на экран помещалось). Вдруг ещё кому понадобится...

Comment: @Akina,окей ) Вас понял)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря комментариям нашел решение для задачи.

Перед началом цикла создаю переменную с таким шаблоном запроса.

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO items (res_id, log_id, link, title, content, n_date, nd_date, s_date, not_date) VALUES'''
```

Потом внутри цикла выполняю конкатенацию:

```
sql +=  ''',('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')''' % (
                         res_id,
                         log_id,
                         str(resource_link),
                         str(item_title),
                         str(item_content),
                         str(n_date),
                         nd_date,
                         s_date,
                         not_date
                        )
```

В итоге у меня переменная `sql` содержит в себе запрос с нужными мне данными:

```
INSERT INTO items (res_id, log_id, link, title, content, n_date, nd_date, s_date, not_date) VALUES ('35', '1', 'http://bryansk-news.net/society/2019/10/07/37428.html', 'бла-бла'
', 'Added by Raha', '1570402602', '1570429215.989103', '2019-10-07') 
VALUES ('35', '1', 'http://bryansk-news.net/society/2019/10/07/37429.html', 
'бла-бла', 'Added by Raha', '1570402845', '1570429217.0539544', '2019-10-07')
```

Comment: Как вы думаете, изменится ли смысл вопроса, или решение в ответе перестанет работать, если ограничить содержимое данных для колонки content 1-им или 2-мя словами? Или надо всё таки обязательно всем прочесть, что: _Ирина Новикова, педагог из города Унеча Брянской области, вооружилась фотоаппаратом и решила запечатлеть резные оконные ставни брянских домиков._?

Comment: @0xdb,вы сделали моё настроение XD ) Хорошо я изменю содержимое )